# How can I cast a (ReadOnly)Span<Dog> into a (ReadOnly)Span<Animal> or vice-versa?

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance

Listing out the variations since Google has no useful results:

- Can I cast a `Span<Dog>` into a `Span<Animal>`?
- Can I cast a `Span<Animal>` into a `Span<Dog>`?
- Can I cast a `ReadOnlySpan<Dog>` into a `ReadOnlySpan<Animal>`?
- Can I cast a `ReadOnlySpan<Animal>` into a `ReadOnlySpan<Dog>`?

Attempting to do any of these yields the same errors, so I figure this is all one question.

Example of Problem:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }

void Main() {
    Dog[] dogs = new Dog[10];
    Span<Dog> dogSpan = dogs.AsSpan(0, 10);

    // CS0030 Cannot convert type 'System.Span<Dog>' to 'System.Span<Animal>'
    Span<Animal> animalSpan1 = (Span<Animal>)dogSpan;

    // CS0453 The type 'Dog' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TFrom' in the generic type or method 'MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>(ReadOnlySpan<TFrom>)'
    // CS0453 The type 'Animal' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>(ReadOnlySpan<TFrom>)'
    Span<Animal> animalSpan2 = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Dog, Animal>(dogSpan);
}
```

I'd be OK with an unsafe cast and the runtime exploding if I pass a Giraffe in a `Span<Dog>`. Searching "span cast items C#" on Google brings up reinterpret casts (e.g. `Span<byte>` to `Span<int>`) which isn't what I want. If this isn't possible, where is the documentation stating so?

I'm using ReadOnlySpan to represent ranges of a read-only managed array (say, an Animal[]). Consumers handle specific Animal implementations (e.g. a GiraffeHandler takes a `ReadOnlySpan<Animal>` and treats it as a `ReadOnlySpan<Giraffe>`).

I recognize an alternative solution would be to allocate an array copy & make a span out of that, or to perform the cast every time I take an element out of the span (perhaps via wrapping the span in a ref struct), but both of these are ugly... I'd prefer to cast the actual `Span<Animal>` to a `Span<Dog>` (or vice versa) if possible, or learn why that's not possible otherwise.

Comment: Keywords for google: `Span<T>` cast items reference types object array, polymorphism covariance contravariance MemoryMarshal.Cast ReadOnlySpan object inheritance zero-copy.

Comment: Making `Animal` and `Dog` structs and losing the inheritance will make **CS0453** go away, but not sure of the results...